# How can I use sys.sp_MSforeachtable with different schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I use `SQL Server 2008 R2` and I want work with `Change Data Capture`.

I want run this command for my all `Tables`

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table 
    @source_schema = N'dbo', 
    @source_name   = N'TestTable', 
    @role_name     = NULL
```

I write this SQL statement .

```
Declare @Command NVarchar(Max)
Set @Command = '
                   EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table 
                                    @source_schema = N''dbo'', 
                                    @source_name   = N''?'', 
                                    @role_name     = NULL 
                '
Exec sys.sp_MSforeachtable @Command
```

But I use several `Schema` in my database ?

How can I use `sys.sp_MSforeachtable` with different schema ?

Comment: Did you get this to work? The answer doesn't work for me and it only does a select where I changed it to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like this :

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 
               'select SUBSTRING(''?'', 0, 
                                  charindex(''.'', ''?'')),
                       SUBSTRING(''?'', charindex(''.'', ''?'') + 1, len(''?''))'
```

Please don't use cursor, and instead of sysview, you could have information_schema.tables

Comment: if this is a comment on my answer, you can put it as a comment ;) Right for information_schema.tables, but the "don't use cursor" doesn't seem really meaningfull in this case.

Comment: well cursor is not suggested as it's not optimized by sql server optimizer. At least that the information i add from my training in 2005. It's always better to use a loop and when it's possible doing in one transaction

Comment: Well, yes, in general. In this case, this is a "one shot" action (not an "often called" sp).

Comment: If you look at the source for `sp_MSforeachtable` you'll see that it... uses a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to work with sys views for that kind of needs

```
declare @schemaName nvarchar(max);
declare @tableName nvarchar(max);

declare curs CURSOR FOR 
        select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 

OPEN curs
FETCH curs into @schemaName, @tableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


    EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = @schemaName, @source_name = @tableName, @role_name = null
    FETCH curs into @schemaName, @tableName;

END
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Comment: Merci but i want fond a way for use sp_MSforeachtable with two